# Any way to cat few lines of man page to show on stdout for reference?

Tags: man, stdout

This is a simple question. Trying my best to put it in simple word. Hope you get it without much confusion -

I read a man page for some command-switch/option which has a long description. I read it, press `q` to escape and try the option. But then I do need to go back to same man page section for some more info. So, I repeat the steps

I would like to know if there is any way to output the contents of man page onto the stdout for referring it quickly.

For example let's take short-one `cal`, may be something like

> cat `man cal`

would be effective and help achieve the desired requirement.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you mean putting the `man` output onto the shell and not removing it when you press `q`?

Answer (score 9):

You could run the output of `man` into the `col` command and then pipe this to `less`. Once in `less` you can drop to a shell while still maintaining your location in `less`.

```
$ man col | col -b | less
```

Once in `less` you can use `!bash` to get to a prompt to do what you want. When you're done you type `exit` to return back to your location in `less`.

#### Example

Here's a demo showing the whole operation.

[image: ss of demo]

#### Tell man to use a different pager

You can also tell `man` to use different pagers via the `-P` switch. So we could streamline the above method like so:

```
$ man -P less col
```

This is invoking `man` and then outputting the contents of the page to `less`, where again we can use `!bash` to get to a shell. To return we use the same steps as above, `exit`.

#### What's wrong with the default pager?

Actually nothing.

```
$ man col
```

It too can take the command `!bash` to escape to a shell, where again we can type `exit` to get back to the location where we were previously within the man page.

#### What else?

If you're feeling really crazy you can use `vim` as an alternative pager too. Setting this up is a bit of a task but it's doable, directions for doing so are here in the vim wikia topic titled: [Using vim as a man-page viewer under Unix](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_as_a_man-page_viewer_under_Unix).

Don't let the above page fool you, it doesn't just cover `vim` methods. That topic covers dozens of ways you can change your man page pager in addition to using `vim`.

Comment: Ctrl+Z and `fg` should work too. I guess this depends on what exactly you want to do at that prompt. To be closer to what appears to be the intent of the OP's example, just remove the piping into `less` (`man col | col -b`).

Comment: Sorry to bother you. What are the explicit differences between `man col | col -b | less` and `man col | less`? Seems both of them return to original scroll position of man page after typing `!bash` and `exit`.

Comment: @IvanChau - the `col -b` is needed when you encounter a man page that is explicitly in `troff` format. It's discussed here a bit: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15855/how-to-dump-a-man-page

Answer (score 6):

You can pipe the output of `man` through whatever command you like.

```
man cal | head
man cal | cat
```

If you want the man page (or at least the part you've scrolled through) to remain in the terminal's scrollback buffer when you exit less, run

```
LESS=-X man cal
```

(this may have strange effects on some terminals though.)

If you're reading a man page and want to try something out, the easiest way is to keep the man page open in one terminal and have a shell prompt in another terminal. If possible, arrange for both terminals to be visible on-screen at the same time. You can use [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [Tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) if you can't run two terminal emulator windows for some reason.

If you want to do everything in the same terminal, you can suspend the `man` command by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and go back to it with the command `fg`. If you have several suspended or backgrounded commands, `fg` resumes the latest to have been in the foreground; typing `%1`, `%2`, etc. resumes one designated by its job number.

Answer (score 1):

As [slm already pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103623/43779), you can use [`col`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/col) to filter reverse line feeds from the output of `man`, then pipe that output further. To output a few lines from the beginning of a manual page, you can combine this with [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head), e.g. to output the first twenty lines:

```
$ man cal | col -b | head -n 20
```

How about outputting each line which looks like an option description:

```
$ man cal | col -b | grep -A1 "^\s*-"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
PAGER="cat" man cal
```

... at least that's the syntax for `bash`. The content of the variable `PAGER` is used to display the man page. If you set `PAGER="cat"` it will write it to stdout. If you set `PAGER="pastebinit"` you end up posting man-pages to pastebin.

Of course this only solves the "output the contents of man page onto the stdout"