# grep the man page of a command for hyphenated options

Tags: grep, man, options

When I grep the man page of the `find` command for matches to `type` it returns a lot of search results that I don't want. Instead I want to use a command that returns *only* the search results for `-type`.

The command `man find | grep -type` doesn't work. It returns:

```
grep: invalid option -- 't'
```

Comment: Do you want just the individual lines of the formatted man page that contain the string `-type`, or do you want, say, the entire paragraph or two that describes what `-type` does?

Comment: I want to know how to do it both ways, grepping for the individual lines that contain the string `-type` would be enough for the way I usually search the man pages, however returning the entire paragraph or two that describes what `-type` does would be very useful to do at least one time.

Comment: BTW, if viewing a web page is an alternative, Idan Kamara at explainshell.com has done a great job of extracting the portions of man pages that describe command options. See, for example, http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+-type+f to see just what the `-type` option does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to grep for a pattern beginning with a hyphen, use `--` before the pattern you specify.

```
man find | grep -- -type
```

If you want more info, for example the entire section describing an option, you *could* try using Sed:

```
$ man find | sed -n '/-mindepth/,/^$/p'
   -mindepth levels
          Do  not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels (a
          non-negative integer).  -mindepth  1  means  process  all  files
          except the command line arguments.
```

However, this won't work for every option you might search for.  For example:

```
$ man find | sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*-type/,/^$/p'
   -type c
          File is of type c:
```

Not very helpful.  Worse, for some options you could be misled into thinking you'd read the whole text about the option when you really hadn't.  For example, searching `-delete` omits the very important WARNING contained as a *second* paragraph under that heading.

---

My recommendation is to use a standard call to `man` with the `LESS` environment variable set.  I use it quite commonly in my answers on this site.

```
LESS='+/^[[:space:]]*-type' man find
```

To learn more about how this works, see:

```
LESS='+/^[[:space:]]*LESS ' man less
LESS='+/\+cmd' man less
LESS='+/\/' man less
```

---

If you just want to find the option quickly and interactively in the man page, learn to use `less`'s search capabilities.  And also see:

- [How do I use man pages to learn how to use commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193815/135943)

Comment: Thank you for posting. The commands in your answer returned the results that I was looking for. I will accept an answer after a day or two, so please be patient.

Comment: @karel, no problem, I'm very patient.  :)  A little puzzled, though: I know you can't start a *bounty* on a question for two days, but I believe the time limit before you can accept an answer is only 15 minutes or so.

Comment: `man find | sed -n '/-type/,/^$/p'` gives lot more than what you posted as it will match `-type` anywhere in the line... am working on small script myself to search man or help (for builtin) and currently using `awk` which still has few quirks to solve.. `awk -v RS= -v rx="^\\\s*$arg\\\>" '$0 ~ rx' "$file"` where `arg` would be `-type` in this case

Comment: @Sundeep, true.  I updated with the actual command used.  I didn't think it crucial because my point is that's *not* a good way to get the data, but it's better this way; thanks.

Comment: BTW, @Sundeep, you might want to try parsing the underlying `troff` files containing the original man page info with format information, instead of the text output of the `man` command.

Comment: @Wildcard will check it out, thanks... irregular spacing between different man pages makes it lot tougher and require patches.. my script so far works for most of my use cases though, needed a script to work a bit like explainshell, for ex: `ch ls -latr -h`

Comment: @Sundeep, [here's the starting point for you](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15859/135943).  (Be sure to follow the link in that answer.)  There's a LOT to know about `troff`.  Ping me in chat when you finish diving down the rabbit hole.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard, here's my [current version of script](https://github.com/learnbyexample/command_help) .. as you've pointed out in this answer, it has its drawbacks but works well for many cases... will check out the `groff` rabbit hole and get back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Or pipe to `less` and feed that a search term:

```
man 1 find | less -p ' -type'
```

(This may fail depending on exactly what `less` is feed, e.g. if `-type` has been bolded up with backspaces.)

Comment: Pipe it through `col -bx` first.